# AWS ruby sdk for Async non blocking calls

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, amazon-web-services, sdk

I want to publish custom application level metrics to be pushed to aws cloudwatch service. (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/CloudWatch/Client.html#put_metric_data-instance_method), so that I can see all the metrics both system and application level custom metrics in AWS dashboard. This way I don't have to use third party monitoring solution like graphite etc.

The thing here is that I don't want my application to get slowed down by making blocking calls to push metrics. Is there way I can make async calls (fire and forget) using aws ruby sdk? I know there are Async client in Java SDK but can't find anything for ruby sdk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no async abstraction for the AWS SDK for Ruby.